# How to navigate to a link from dropdown menu "vb.net"

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have finished WebBrowser and drop-down menu to bookmark my links, and it's works.

**But If I click on that link it dose not navigate to that link
I used this code.** and really I don't know what exactly I must use after .Navigate() I tried everything and it's not work with me

```
  Private Sub ListToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListToolStripMenuItem.Click
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Navigate()

    End Sub
```

This code below for bookmark any links "add" if someone need it to know exactly how it's work.

```
 Private Sub AddToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddToolStripMenuItem.Click
        My.Settings.bookmarks.Add(WebBrowser1.Url.ToString)
        ListToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear()
        For Each item As String In My.Settings.bookmarks
            ListToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item)
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: You should be getting an error since that `Navigate()` method needs a URL parameter.

Comment: Ya that's true, I know everything is right, but after Navigate() I tried everything, from what I know if there is no tabs will be after that "Url.ToString" but with tabs I really don't know, I search a lot to find what exactly must add after Navigate, and tried a lot of things nothing work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your ToolStrip item is the URL, try casting the sender to get the value and pass that in the Navigate parameter:

```
Private Sub ListToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim web As WebBrowser = TryCast(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser)
  If web IsNot Nothing Then
    web.Navigate(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Text)
  End If
End Sub
```

It also looks like your menu items don't have a click event handler attached to them:

```
ListToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item, Nothing, _
                                        AddressOf ListToolStripMenuItem_Click)
```

Comment: The first part dose not work too! nothing happen when I click on links inside my drop-down menu, I added the second part to "add item"

Comment: @IT_GUY This works on my machine, so I can't see what you are doing in your code.  You have to do the second part in order to get the first part to work.  As always, use the debugger to put breaks in the code and step through the code line by line to see what is happening.

Comment: oh it's work :D you have changed the way of adding the links that's brilliant , did you know I stuck at this for 3 weeks!, Thanks a lot

Comment: There is a tiny problem here, it's work! if I add link and then click on it from drop-down menu, but if I closed the app then open it; the same link will not be able to be open, there is no error when I debug it at all? can you gives me a hint and I will try to solve it

Comment: @IT_GUY I can't see your code.  Clearly look at the loading of the form where you load your bookmark menu items.  Make sure you are attaching the click event handler.